# Broadcast Receiver is not receiving the intent after I change the Intent action

Tags: android, android-intent, android-broadcastreceiver

I am trying to build a simple count down timer app. MainActivity starts a service(TimerService). This service starts a CountDownTimer. After every tick, I send out a broadcast to update my view in the MainActivity. The view time updates till the last tick. When the CountDownTimer finishes, I am creating an intent with another action to indicate that timer has finished. But the intent is not being received by BroadcastReceiver.

This is my CountDownTimer code.

```
    @Override
    public void onFinish() {
        Log.i(TAG, "Timer finished");
        Intent notifyMainAct = new Intent(Constants.TIME_OVER);
        notifyMainAct.putExtra(Constants.GET_TIMER_VALUE,String.valueOf(0));
        sendBroadcast(notifyMainAct);
        stopSelf(serviceStartId);
        Log.i(TAG, "Stopping service " +serviceStartId);

    }

    @Override
    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        long minRemaining = millisUntilFinished/60000;
        Log.i(TAG, "On Tick: "+String.valueOf(minRemaining));
        Intent notifyMainAct = new Intent(Constants.BROADCAST_ACTION);
        notifyMainAct.putExtra(Constants.GET_TIMER_VALUE,String.valueOf(minRemaining));
        sendBroadcast(notifyMainAct);
    }
```

This is my BroadcastReceiver in the MainActivity.

```
 private BroadcastReceiver timerCountReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.i(TAG, "On receiving intent");
        String action = intent.getAction();
        Log.i(TAG, action);
        if(action.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.BROADCAST_ACTION)) {
            String timerCount = intent.getExtras().getString(Constants.GET_TIMER_VALUE);
            Log.i(TAG, " Timer count received in Activity "+timerCount);
            time_remaining.setText(timerCount);

        }
        else if(action.equalsIgnoreCase(Constants.TIME_OVER)){
            usr_msg.setText("Time OVER");
        }
    }
};
```

This is my manifest.xml.

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.tony">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <service
        android:name=".TimerService"
        android:enabled="true"
        android:exported="false">
    </service>
</application>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was a minor thing.I had forgotten to register the intent actions while registering the BroadcastReceiver inside the onResume() method.

```
@Override
public void onResume(){
    super.onResume();
    IntentFilter receiverFilter = new IntentFilter();
    receiverFilter.addAction(Constants.BROADCAST_ACTION);
    receiverFilter.addAction(Constants.TIME_OVER_ACTION);
    registerReceiver(timerCountReceiver, receiverFilter);

}
```